# Remove space after cases environment

Tags: spacing, cases

After I write a begin cases environment, usually there appears a big space which bothers me. I do not know how to remove it.

```
$\Hom(V,U)=\begin{cases}\{i:V\rightarrow U\vert i(v)=v, \forall v\in V\}, \text{ dac\u a } V\subset U\\
\emptyset, \text{ altfel}\end{cases}$.
```

It looks something like this:[image]

Can you give me any suggestions?

Comment: Did you really have `/]` in your code?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The code snippet you've posted does *not* give rise to the associated screenshot, since the `.` (dot) occurs before `\end{cases}`. Please fix either the code or the screenshot. Incidentally, is `\ri` a synonym for `\to`?

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, the code was part of a bigger code. \ri is a synonym for \rightarrow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code snippet -- at least the one that was posted initially -- cannot give rise to the screenshot you've posted as the `.` ("period", "full stop") symbol occurs *before* `\end{cases}`.

I suggest you put a comma at the end of the first line of the `cases` environment and a period at the end of the second -- before the `\end{cases}` statement.

In addition to fixing some obvious typos, you may want to look into using the `cases` environment more systematically, specifically, by using the feature of splitting the result and conditioning information via an `&` character.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}
\let\ri\rightarrow

\begin{document}
\[
\Hom(V,U)=
% Don't use "\vert" here; instead, use "\mid"
% And, don't use ":" here; instead, use "\colon"
\begin{cases}      
    \{i\colon V\ri U \mid i(v)=v, \forall v\in V\} & \text{dac\u a $V\subset U$,}\\
    \emptyset & \text{altfel.}
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

`cases` was designed as a matrix to have two horizontal columns, separated by `\quad`, which is triggered by `&`.  the second column was intended to hold the explanation.

you have run the two parts together, and the `\quad` intended to come between
them has instead been added at the end, before the period.

here is the intended use of this environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}
\let\ri\rightarrow

\begin{document}
\[
\Hom(V,U)=
\begin{cases}      
    \{i\colon V\ri U \vert i(v)=v, \forall v\in V\}
      & \text{dac\u a $V\subset U$,}\\
    \emptyset & \text{altfel}
\end{cases} .
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

by the way, mico's recommendation to use `\mid` rather than `\vert` is a good one.